# How to find all permutations?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a list:

```
n = ['n1','n2','n3','n4','n5','n6']
```

What I want is build a np.array that contains all permutations of the list.
But there is a limit that I want to divide the matrix equally into 3 parts in order. The same combinations in a part would only take one. For example:

```
['n1','n2','n3','n4','n5','n6']
```

and

```
['n2','n1','n3','n4','n5','n6']
```

would be same, so the final np.array should only have one of them.
Another example:

```
['n1','n2','n3','n4','n5','n6']
```

and

```
['n1','n3','n2','n4','n5','n6']
```

would be different, because the "n1,n2" of first list and the "n1,n3" of second list are both in first part. The final np.array shoul have them both.

How do I do it?

Any help would be great!

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: try itertools permutation ?

Comment: I did, but don't know how to drop duplicates

Comment: I cant make sense of how you select which permutaions are allowed but to get the permutaions use `itertools.permutaion` then loop through them using an `if.. ` to select which are valid

Comment: Question is very unclear. do you want to find permutations or combinations? would n1, n2 , n4... and n2 , n3 , n4... be different or same in your condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand what you're trying to do. The following isnt very pretty code but it works. I grab all the permutations, and then check for sorted uniqueness against elements in a growing list to which I append new unique permutations:

```
from itertools import permutations

n = ['n1','n2','n3','n4','n5','n6']

# This will hold the collection of unique groupings
unique_groups = [[], [], []]

for x in permutations(n):
    # divide into groups, and sort to be able to compare against unique_groups
    sorted_groups = [sorted(x[0:2]), sorted(x[2:4]), sorted(x[4:6])]

    u1, u2, u3 = unique_groups
    s1, s2, s3 = sorted_groups

    # check that all three groups are unique, and append if so
    if (s1 not in u1) and (s2 not in u2) and (s3 not in u3):
        u1.append(s1)
        u2.append(s2)
        u3.append(s3)

# Helper function to flatten the 3x3 output lists into 9x1 :  
def flatten(l):
    return [item for sublist in l for item in sublist]

result = [flatten(l) for l in zip(*(unique_groups))]
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Reshape your arrays, 
Sort them by pairs, 
Convert to DataFrame, 
and remove duplicates.

Assuming lol is your list of lists:

```
res=[]
for l in lol:
    new_l = np.sort(np.reshape(l,(-1,2))).reshape(1,-1)[0]
    res.append(new_l)
df=pd.DataFrame(res)
res = df.drop_duplicates().values.tolist()
```

example:

```
lol = [['n1','n2','n3','n4','n5','n6'],
       ['n2','n1','n3','n4','n5','n6'],
       ['n1','n3','n2','n4','n5','n6']]

res = [['n1', 'n2', 'n3', 'n4', 'n5', 'n6'],
       ['n1', 'n3', 'n2', 'n4', 'n5', 'n6']]
```